Copy specific values from a cells and then add them above
I have the following dataframe with large amounts of data.

C1  C2      C3      C4
     t # 0 
e   10001   252207  CAT
    t # 1       
e   100018  219559  DOG
    t # 2       
e   100068  251102  CAT
    t # 3       
e   100089  107320  LION
    t # 4       
e   100110  250975  TIGER
    t # 5       
e   100111  28540   TIGER
    t # 6       
e   100112  252253  COW
    t # 7       
e   100157  17883   COW
    t # 8       
e   100158  106226  DOG
    t # 9       
e   100189  32004   CAT
e   100189  250979  DOG
e   100189  107997  CAT
    t # 10      
e   100190  251325  LION
e   100190  251325  LION
e   100190  250999  LION
    t # 11      
e   100194  250979  COW
e   100194  65072   COW
.   ...     ...     ... 
    t # 10000   
e   200194  550979  COW
e   200194  565072  COW

If there is t # {i} in C2, then the other columns in this row are empty
What I would like to achieve is to copy the existing numeric values from C2 and C3 - from one t # {i} to the next t # {i+1} and when C1 has a value of e - and insert them sequentially into C2 above in such a way that they do not repeat and that in C1 for these values there is always the letter v, while in C3 there can be anything different, the most readable would be to assign them, values from 1 upwards. C4 always remains empty.
Below the output I would like to achieve.

C1  C2      C3      C4
     t # 0 
v   10001    1
v   252207   2
e   10001   252207  CAT
    t # 1   
v   100018   1
v   219559   2  
e   100018  219559  DOG
    t # 2
v   100068  1
v   251102  2           
e   100068  251102  CAT
    t # 3       
v   100089  1
v   107320  2       
e   100089  107320  LION
    t # 4       
v   100110  1
v   250975  2       
e   100110  250975  TIGER
    t # 5       
v   100111  1
v   28540  2        
e   100111  28540   TIGER
    t # 6   
v   100112  1
v   252253  2           
e   100112  252253  COW
    t # 7   
v   100068  1
v   251102  2           
e   100157  17883   COW
    t # 8   
v   100158  1
v   106226  2           
e   100158  106226  DOG
    t # 9   
v   100189  1
v   32004   2       
v   250979  3
v   107997  4           
e   100189  32004   CAT
e   100189  250979  DOG
e   100189  107997  CAT
    t # 10      
v   100190  1
v   251325  2       
v   251325  3
v   250999  4       
e   100190  251325  LION
e   100190  251325  LION
e   100190  250999  LION
    t # 11      
v   100194  1
v   250979  2       
v   65072   3
e   100194  250979  COW
e   100194  65072   COW
    t # 10000   
v   200194  1
v   550979  2       
v   565072  3
e   200194  550979  COW
e   200194  565072  COW

I absolutely do not know how I can do this, For any help thanks.
EDIT: I use txt file in df
with open("results123.txt", "r") as f:
    text = [line.split() for line in f]

df = pandas.DataFrame(
    text,
    columns=['C1','C2','C3','C4']
)

and my df looks like this:
import json
d = df.to_dict(orient='records')
print(d)
[{'C1': 't', 'C2': '#', 'C3': '0', 'C4': None}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': '10001', 'C3': '252207', 'C4': 'BOVINI'}, {'C1': 't', 'C2': '#', 'C3': '1', 'C4': None}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': '100018', 'C3': '219559', 'C4': 'BOVINI'}, {'C1': 't', 'C2': '#', 'C3': '2', 'C4': None}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': '100068', 'C3': '251102', 'C4': 'BOVINI'}, {'C1': 't', 'C2': '#', 'C3': '3', 'C4': None}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': '100089', 'C3': '107320', 'C4': 'BOVINI'}, {'C1': 't', 'C2': '#', 'C3': '4', 'C4': None}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': '100110', 'C3': '250975', 'C4': 'BOVINI'}, {'C1': 't', 'C2': '#', 'C3': '5', 'C4': None}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': '100111', 'C3': '28540', 'C4': 'BOVINI'}, {'C1': 't', 'C2': '#', 'C3': '6', 'C4': None}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': '100112', 'C3': '252253', 'C4': 'BOVINI'}, {'C1': 't', 'C2': '#', 'C3': '7', 'C4': None}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': '100157', 'C3': '17883', 'C4': 'BOVINI'}, {'C1': 't', 'C2': '#', 'C3': '8', 'C4': None}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': '100158', 'C3': '106226', 'C4': 'BOVINI'}, {'C1': 't', 'C2': '#', 'C3': '9', 'C4': None}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': '100189', 'C3': '32004', 'C4': 'BOVINI'}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': '100189', 'C3': '250979', 'C4': 'BOVINI'}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': '100189', 'C3': '107997', 'C4': 'BOVINI'}, {'C1': 't', 'C2': '#', 'C3': '10', 'C4': None}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': '100190', 'C3': '251325', 'C4': 'BOVINI'}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': '100190', 'C3': '251325', 'C4': 'BOVINI'}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': '100190', 'C3': '250999', 'C4': 'BOVINI'}, {'C1': 't', 'C2': '#', 'C3': '11', 'C4': None}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': '100194', 'C3': '250979', 'C4': 'BOVINI'}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': '100194', 'C3': '65072', 'C4': 'BOVINI'}, {'C1': 't', 'C2': '#', 'C3': '12', 'C4': None}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': '100203', 'C3': '250979', 'C4': 'BOVINI'}, {'C1': 't', 'C2': '#', 'C3': '13', 'C4': None}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': '100224', 'C3': '234727', 'C4': 'BOVINI'}, {'C1': 't', 'C2': '#', 'C3': '14', 'C4': None}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': '100229', 'C3': '253351', 'C4': 'BOVINI'}, {'C1': 't', 'C2': '#', 'C3': '15', 'C4': None}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': '100230', 'C3': '228074', 'C4': 'BOVINI'}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': '100230', 'C3': '182318', 'C4': 'BOVINI'}, {'C1': 't', 'C2': '#', 'C3': '16', 'C4': None}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': '100231', 'C3': '252665', 'C4': 'BOVINI'}, {'C1': 't', 'C2': '#', 'C3': '17', 'C4': None}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': '100269', 'C3': '41716', 'C4': 'BOVINI'}, {'C1': 't', 'C2': '#', 'C3': '18', 'C4': None}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': '100277', 'C3': '251094', 'C4': 'BOVINI'}, {'C1': 't', 'C2': '#', 'C3': '19', 'C4': None}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': '100281', 'C3': '253887', 'C4': 'BOVINI'}, {'C1': 't', 'C2': '#', 'C3': '20', 'C4': None}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': '100283', 'C3': '20766', 'C4': 'BOVINI'}, {'C1': 't', 'C2': '#', 'C3': '21', 'C4': None}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': '100288', 'C3': '251001', 'C4': 'BOVINI'}, {'C1': 't', 'C2': '#', 'C3': '22', 'C4': None}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': '10029', 'C3': '250979', 'C4': 'BOVINI'}, {'C1': 't', 'C2': '#', 'C3': '23', 'C4': None}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': '100290', 'C3': '197427', 'C4': 'BOVINI'}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': '100290', 'C3': '41716', 'C4': 'BOVINI'}, {'C1': 't', 'C2': '#', 'C3': '24', 'C4': None}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': 'ID_NODO_OR', 'C3': 'ID_NODO_DEST', 'C4': 'SPECIE'}, {'C1': 'e', 'C2': 'ID_NODO_OR', 'C3': 'ID_NODO_DEST', 'C4': 'SPECIE'}]



I use a txt file that looks like the one I indicated above

I have this error: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'dtype'

I've added my code and how my df looks like

You can iterate through the rows and use startswith() on row C2, in addition to the other condition:
import pandas as pd

def get_rows(df):
    Vs, res = 1, []
    for _, r in df.iterrows():
        if r['C2'].startswith('t #'):
            Vs = 1
        elif r['C1'] == 'e':
            res.append(['v', r['C2'], str(Vs), None])
            Vs += 1
        res.append([r['C1'], r['C2'], r['C3'], r['C4']])
    return pd.DataFrame(res, columns=df.columns)


D = [
    {"C1": "t", "C2": "#", "C3": "0", "C4": None},
    {"C1": "e", "C2": "10001", "C3": "252207", "C4": "BOVINI"},
    {"C1": "t", "C2": "#", "C3": "1", "C4": None},
    {"C1": "e", "C2": "100018", "C3": "219559", "C4": "BOVINI"},
    {"C1": "t", "C2": "#", "C3": "2", "C4": None},
    {"C1": "e", "C2": "100068", "C3": "251102", "C4": "BOVINI"}
]

print(get_rows(pd.DataFrame(D)))


Prints

  C1      C2      C3      C4
0  t       #       0    None
1  v   10001       1    None
2  e   10001  252207  BOVINI
3  t       #       1    None
4  v  100018       2    None
5  e  100018  219559  BOVINI
6  t       #       2    None
7  v  100068       3    None
8  e  100068  251102  BOVINI



Write:
you can simply add these lines at the end of function:
    res = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=df.columns)
    res.to_csv(filename, sep='\t', index=False, header=False)



But I wouldn't want to get rid of the lines where C1 contains e. I would like to add to what I have your output

ok, I made it. Thank you so much for your help, you helped me tremendously

I've now looked at my full collection and I'm still missing two things. I would also like the numeric values in column C3 to be added as you did with those in column C2. Also, I would like these values to go all the way up until they encounter 't # {i}', and not just by one so that at the beginning there are values with v, and then with e

Also, the values from C2 are repeated, and I would prefer to avoid this

@Fortides You can also uncheck the accepted answer. So that other people may answer... Or you can post new questions with the new code..

I can create something thanks to you, thanks again

@Fortides It's best to do it step by step so that you'd become comfortable with Pandas. Ask one question that requires to do one task only. Then, update your DF and ask a new question and update your DF again. Eventually, you can reduce the extra work. Most importantly these are linear algorithms. Time complexity does not matter. Function by function. Each function should carry out doing one specific task, only.
